# Any prepopulated mailbox to test email clients?

Tags: email, software-testing

I would like to test several email clients, some of them still bing in early development. I'm reluctant to use my own mailboxes for this.

Is there any preopulated mailbox to which I can connect in IMAP to download messages, so that I can test several email clients?

N.B. I don't need to send messages, as it's mostly to test tagging and search features.

Comment: "I'm reluctant to use my own mailboxes for this" - why not use copies then?  Filing that, sign up for lots of spam with a throwaway address ;-)

Comment: Something like https://temp-mail.org/en/ to a local client?

Comment: @Mawg: First, for privacy reasons: without becoming paranoid, each mail client possibly adds one more eye into your private life  and/or your company. The more ones you test, the higher the risk. Second because migrating mailboxes to a copy requires time.

Comment: @Mihael Nancarrow: I don't need a temporary mailbox, that's not my goal. One of the things that I want to test are "tagging" and search features. I don't want to have writing dozen of messages to populate the mailbox. Hence the need for a prepopulated mailbox. I assume the guys working with artificial intelligence can generate messages that look like if they were written by humans.

Comment: If you don't want to use your own email id then create your fake id from [fake email generator](https://fakedetail.com/fake-mail-generator/gmail).